# Is the quarkus-amazon-lambda production ready?

Tags: quarkus

> This technology is considered preview.

The above quote is from https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda
This is the blocker to consider the extension for the production usage.
What is the ETA for reaching the "stable" status?

Thanks, Alex